# logout segue en swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy usando firebase para gestionar el inicio y cierre de sesión de los usuarios, usando el método Auth.logOut, pero he usado unwind segue y poopToRoot para regresar al usuario a la ventana de login una vez que presione el boton de logout y no logro hacer que funcione, pues me marca errores o simplemente no pasa nada.

Este es mi método y funciona correctamente el cierre de sesión:

```
@IBAction func logOutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alertaCierre = UIAlertController(title: "Cerrar Sesión",
                                         message: "¿Estás seguro(a) que quieres cerrar sesión?",
                                         preferredStyle: .actionSheet) // Se crea una variable de tipo UIAlert donde vamos a mostrar el mensaje
    
    alertaCierre.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar",
                                         style: .cancel,
                                         handler: nil)) // Se crea un boton dentro de esta alerta el cual permitira cancelar la accion
    
    
    alertaCierre.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cerrar Sesión", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in 
        AuthManager.shared.logoutUsuario(completion: {success in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                    print("Logout")
                }
                else{
                    // Error en cerrar sesión
                    fatalError("No se pudo cerrar sesión")
                }
            }
        })
    }))
    
    // instancias de alerta de mensaje
    alertaCierre.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableView
    alertaCierre.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = tableView.bounds
    // mostrar alerta en pantalla
    present(alertaCierre, animated: true)
    
}
```

[image: y este es mi archivo Main:]

Cree una instancia del ViewController pero la pantalla de la app se pone en negro:

```
@IBAction func logOutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alertaCierre = UIAlertController(title: "Cerrar Sesión",
                                         message: "¿Estás seguro(a) que quieres cerrar sesión?",
                                         preferredStyle: .actionSheet) // Se crea una variable de tipo UIAlert donde vamos a mostrar el mensaje
    
    alertaCierre.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar",
                                         style: .cancel,
                                         handler: nil)) // Se crea un boton dentro de esta alerta el cual permitira cancelar la accion
    
    // Se crea un boton dentro de esta alerta el cual permitira seguir con el proceso
    alertaCierre.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cerrar Sesión", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in // Como es de tipo .destructive, continúa con el cierre de sesión
        AuthManager.shared.logoutUsuario(completion: {success in // Accedemos a la funcion de logout implementada en authManager controller
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    // Se regresa a la vista de Login en caso de que todo funcionó correctamente
                    let loginVC = LoginViewController()
                    loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(loginVC, animated: true){
                        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                    }
                    print("Logout exitoso")
                }
                else{
                    // Error en cerrar sesión
                    fatalError("No se pudo cerrar sesión")
                }
            }
        })
    }))
```

Comment: Según la imagen del flujo no creo que el `pop` o el `unwind` llegue al login. Intentaste instanciando el `ViewController` del login con el nombre del storyboard? O creando un segue directamente del botón al `ViewController`.

Comment: Intenté el segue directamente al ViewController del login, pero en realidad no sabía si eso es una buena practica. Lo del instanciarlo con el nombre del storyboard no funciona, es decir, cree una variable para presentarla pero simplemente no pasa nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código de ejemplo, simulo una llamada a una API y si todo es satisfactorio hago el cambio del `ViewController`. Estas dos opciones funcionan:

1. Instanciando el `ViewController` con el `id` en el `Storyboard`:

   ```
   let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Instanciar el view controller.
                let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
                loginViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                //Mostrar el view controller
                self.present(loginViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
   }
   task.resume()
   ```

*Resultado 1:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Creando un `Segue` entre los `ViewController`:

- Con la tecla control presionada, arrastras el segue del origen al destino y seleccionas `show`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Le das un nombre al segue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Usas `performSegue` para llamar al `segue` que creaste:

  ```
   let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Llamas al segue con el nombre del identificador
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: nil)
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
  ```

*Resultado 2:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:**
La transición es diferente para mostrar la diferencia del código. Para que ocupe toda la pantalla debes cambiar la transición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! me funcionó a la perfección la opción 1...

Comment: Aunque tengo una duda más... si me direcciona a mi view controller de login, pero si quiero volver a hacer el recorrido de iniciar sesión y demás... las siguientes storyboards me salen como modal presentation

Comment: Te tocaría cambiar el tipo de transición en el código o como la opción 2.